# MeasureString does not return exact width after rotation

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, text-size

I'm using `MeasureString` method to calculate the width of text but the returned value is not exact. I'm using the following code for calculating text width

```
Size sz = g.MeasureString(text, font);
g.DrawString(text, font, brush, 
             new Rectangle(0, 0, (int)sz.Width, (int)sz.Height), stringFormat);
g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, new Rectangle(0, 0, (int)sz.Width, (int)sz.Height));
```

This works fine without rotation. I'm using the following code to draw rotated text

```
g.RotateTransform(angle);
Size sz = g.MeasureString(text, font);
g.DrawString(text, font, brush, 
             new Rectangle(0, 0, (int)sz.Width, (int)sz.Height), stringFormat);
g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, new Rectangle(0, 0, (int)sz.Width, (int)sz.Height));
```

The width value returned for second code snippet is different from first one and also it's not correct. See the following image

[image: Additional space]

At the bottom of the rectangle there is some additional space after text. The rectangle was drawn based on the width and height of the string so I think this has something to do with `MeasureString` method.

Please share your thoughts on avoiding this

Edit:

More space can be seen if text length is long (say 30 or more characters) .Rotation works fine for angles 0, 90, 180 and 270. Attached a screenshot

[image: At 90 degree]

Comment: Are you sure there isnt a space there? Otherwise the measureString is not accurate sometimes, i would guess even less on rotated text. Why dont you measure the string while its not rotated and just use that value all the time?

Comment: @Vajura, Calculating text size before rotation results in more space

Comment: Looks like the algorithm isn't exact for rotations where the font doesn't line up square on the screen.  You could use GDI+ to do the drawstring and rectangle on a `System.Drawing.Image` (creating an image), then rotate the image itself.  That should correct the problem, as the image would be created first and then the entire calculated image would be rotated.

Comment: @ps2goat, your suggestion can be used for workaround purpose, but I need this for control level. In our control, we support text rotation it works fine till 180 degree, but after 180 degree of rotation we started seeing empty spaces from the point where text should be placed and where it was placed actually. Right now, I'm checking MeasureCharacterRanges and other available methods to calculate range. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms142109%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) format of `MeasureString` which includes `stringformat`. `Typographical` is the recommended one..